# Php redirect, not working

Tags: php, redirect

I have a form with an add user button. If the user is added, the page should redirect to another page which would allow you to edit that user.

What I currently do is:

```
if ($user_added) {
  <META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh CONTENT='0; 
   URL=<php echo $root. "Path1/path2/path3/userEdit.php?ID=".$newUser->GetID(); ?>'>
```

NOTE: ID is not something you can switch to easily, its a different more complicated number that i generate randomly whenever I add users, for the sake of the question i kept it simple.

UPDATE: This changes the page to the userEdit page but it does not load the data from the new user.

Comment: That's not a redirect.  It's also not valid PHP.  I imagine you're getting some errors in your PHP logs and rendering PHP code to the browser.

Comment: "not working" is a crap problem description

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @David No i'm not getting any errors with this. It actually brings up the user edit page but instead of loading the information of the user in the form, it just brings up a blank form.

Comment: @DonCode: I doubt this exact code successfully does that.  But either way, that would mean that the problem has nothing to do with this code.  This is doing exactly what you expect it to.  The `userEdit.php` page, however, doesn't seem to do what you expect.  You need to narrow down the problem with some debugging, we can't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing html and php. PHP redirects can be done with a header BEFORE the page loads like so:
`<?php header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/index.php'); ?>`
But again this only works if the content has not yet been sent.

Also:
`URL=<php echo $root. "Path1/path2/path3/userEdit.php?ID=".$newUser->GetID(); ?>'>`
This is also insecure because any user can access any user's page simply by changing the url.